# Tie loop on array in controller to a button in blade

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, csv

Currently, in my laravel controller, I have a loop on an array

Controller

```
$methodData = $methodcall->dataCall();

foreach($methodData->categories as $category){ 

    $categoryName = $category->category_name;
    $categoryDescription = $category->category_desc;

    foreach($category->products as $product){

        foreach($product->product_info as $info){

            $productCode = $info->productCode;

            foreach($info->productType as $type){

                $quantDetails = $type->quantDetails;
                $desc = $type->desc;

            }

        }

        foreach ($product->prices as $price => $amount) {

            $price_amount = $amount;

        }
    }
}
```

This loops what I need and sets the variables. Then in my blade I have a button

Blade

```
<div>
  <button>Export Info</button>
</div>
```

How can I tie the button to what I've built with that array loop and export it as a csv?

Comment: You are not actually building anything. You probably want to add your result to a `$results` array and then use something like Laravel Excel to quickly convert it to a csv.

Comment: So set $results=array(); before the foreach loop, and then add it to the array at the end? Then build it as a csv in the controller?

Comment: That would work. Although Laravel Excel can also [export collections](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/exports/collection.html). So I'd probably map this into a Collection, do my processing and export that instead. Both would work.

Comment: Hmm ok, I may look into the collection thing. Thanks!